# How AWS WAF detects origin IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, ip, amazon-waf

AWS doc says that

> By default, AWS WAF uses the IP address from the web request origin.

But it doesn't say how it is done. Does WAF check each TCP/IP packet for source address? Or is it done by some other mechanism?

Note: I am not talking about forwarded IP address here. I already know about X-Forwarded-For & similar headers. I am taking about the default case & want to know how WAF detects the immediate IP address where the call is coming from.

Comment: _"Does WAF check each TCP/IP packet for source address?"_ - yes. Or rather at a higher level, the socket connection.